# GPIO input pins give out a volte

Tags: gpio, output

Hi I am controlling a 1960's Lego train trough a motor controller that uses the PWM of the Raspberry pi3 and I have 4 IR sensors that are externally powered with a 3.3V constant power supply, I used python to program the sensors and motor controller, and when I control the motor controller with the raspberry pi the input pins THAT I HAVE SET TO INPUT give out 1V and as input in the code it gives me a constant HI input read and I clean the GPIO pins with the command GPIO.cleanup() after everything.

The code that I am using:

```
## import RPi.GPIO

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


## set numbering to board

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)


## setup GPIO pins

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)


## setting up Pulse Width Module

p = GPIO.PWM(37, 100)
p.start(0)

while True:

    ## updating sensors

    sensor1 = GPIO.input(11)
    sensor2 = GPIO.input(12)
    sensor3 = GPIO.input(13)
    sensor4 = GPIO.input(15)

    p.ChangeDutyCycle(85)

    if sensor1 == 0:
        print('1')

    if sensor2 == 0:
        print('2')

    if sensor3 == 0:
        print('3')

    if sensor4 == 0:
        print('4')
```

How can I fix it? and why is it doing that?

Comment: If those are analog sensors that is a problem.

Comment: but they have worked before, but I will check.

Comment: But would that effect the raspberry pi to output 1v ?

Comment: If the pin is set as an input, its state is generally determined by what it is attached to.  If it is not attached to anything (e.g., if you read a bare input with a voltmeter, which is basically attaching a digital input to an analog input), it has high resistance and an *indeterminate voltage,* aka a [high-Z state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_impedance)  <- As per the second paragraph this is the third state in *three state logic*, the others being low and high.  Outputs are either low or high, inputs that are not pulled up or down are high-Z.